# jquery mobile didn't append div to content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a script which should append some element to the Content div, but it didn't work.
As you see the content of the "messageBox" is arrives from a php file which select the mysql table and the data from it.

Here is the JS file's content:

```
    function getWallMsg(){
    $.getJSON('SELECT_uzenofal.php?callback=?',function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(e){
            $('#posts').append($('<div class="messageBox">'+'<img src="img/profilok/'+e.kep+'"/>'+'<p class="name">'+e.nev+'</p>'+'<p>'+e.uzenet+'</p>'+'<p class="time">'+e.ido+'</p>'+'</div>'));
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    drawNavbar();
    getWallMsg();
});
```

And the html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="fal">
        <!-- header -->
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Üzenőfal
            </h3>
        </div>
        <!-- content -->
        <div data-role="content" id="posts">

        </div>
        <!-- footer -->
        <div class="nav" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be changed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    drawNavbar();
    getWallMsg();
});
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#fal', function(){       
    drawNavbar();
    getWallMsg();
});
```

Basically **`document ready`** should not be used with **`jQuery Mobile`**, to find out more about this take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, to be transparent it is my personal blog. Or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

Basically you are trying to append it on **`document ready`** when page content is not loaded into the **`DOM`**. Instead proper **`jQuery Mobile`** page event, like **`pagebeforeshow`**, should be used.

**EDIT :**

You were adding an incorrect id to the pagebeforeshow even. It should work now.

Comment: Sadly it does not changed :(

Comment: If it is not a problem to you, mail me your code and I will take a look.

Comment: It is not a problem, a moment please :)

Comment: Ok, let me finish my dinner and I will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

could not comment so posting as answer.

```
$('#posts').append($('<div class="messageBox">'+'<img src="img/profilok/'+e.kep+'"/>'+'<p class="name">'+e.nev+'</p>'+'<p>'+e.uzenet+'</p>'+'<p class="time">'+e.ido+'</p>'+'</div>'));
```

have you tried changing above to

```
$('#posts').append('<div class="messageBox">'+'<img src="img/profilok/'+e.kep+'"/>'+'<p class="name">'+e.nev+'</p>'+'<p>'+e.uzenet+'</p>'+'<p class="time">'+e.ido+'</p>'+'</div>');
```